# app upload on heroku does not work

Tags: ruby, heroku, upload

I am tying to upload my first app to heroku but does not work. it gives me a message saying.

" The page you were looking for doesn't exist.You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

I have seen all the similar questions asked on stackoverflow but non of them could solve my case. I am on Rails 4 and my heroku log is as below.

Oh, and I am following the course on OneMonthRails but just curios, do we "need" to use heroku? To me it seems like just a rental server where you can share the development process with some other developers but if I was to make something on my own do I still need to use heroku?

Anyway thank you for looking in to this.

My Log of heroku

```
2013-08-15T02:46:10.396576+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 116.81.12.104 at 2013-08-15 02:46:10 +0000
2013-08-15T02:46:10.397621+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.397621+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.397621+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.397868+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.397621+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.397621+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.397868+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.397868+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.397868+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.397868+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.397868+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398059+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-15T02:46:10.397868+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.397868+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398059+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.397868+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398059+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398059+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398059+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398662+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398662+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398662+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398059+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.397868+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398059+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398662+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398662+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398662+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398662+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398874+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398059+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398059+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398874+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398874+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398874+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398874+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398874+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398059+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398662+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398874+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398874+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398874+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398662+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398874+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-15T02:46:10.398662+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-08-15T02:46:10.403101+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=murmuring-ocean-4579.herokuapp.com fwd="116.81.12.104" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=1351
2013-08-15T02:48:26.146952+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2013-08-15T02:48:26.146952+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147139+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147139+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.145932+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 116.81.12.104 at 2013-08-15 02:48:26 +0000
2013-08-15T02:48:26.145932+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 116.81.12.104 at 2013-08-15 02:48:26 +0000
2013-08-15T02:48:26.146952+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.146952+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147139+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147139+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.146952+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.146952+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.149746+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=murmuring-ocean-4579.herokuapp.com fwd="116.81.12.104" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=1351
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147139+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.146952+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147139+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.146952+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.146952+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.146952+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147317+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147317+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147317+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147139+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147317+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147139+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147796+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147139+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147139+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147317+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147974+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147796+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147317+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147796+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147317+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147974+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147317+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147796+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147317+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147796+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147796+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147796+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147974+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147317+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147974+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147974+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147796+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147974+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147796+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147796+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147974+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147974+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147974+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-08-15T02:48:26.147974+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-15T02:48:26.488666+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=murmuring-ocean-4579.herokuapp.com fwd="116.81.12.104" dyno=web.1 connect=26ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=0
```

Comment: have you tried running this application locally on production environment?

Answer (score 0):

No You don't need to use Heroku. You can do the development on localhost. Also it would be helpful if you told what you've done already.